# how to remove system environment variable by using batch file

Tags: windows-xp

I need to remove system variables from client workstation and my clients are 500+ so I want to provide batch file to user to run himself to delete the system variables.

Comment: I would suggest you start accepting some of the 8 other questions you have asked before you ask people to spend their time answer another one.

Answer (score 2):

get info about environment variables:

> %> reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

and delete the one you want with

> %> reg delete /f /va "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"\XYZ

Answer (score 0):

set *variablename*=

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true